# How can I interact with a new Postgres installation if I can't sudo -u postgres?

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, administrative-privileges

I have installed Postgres on an Ubuntu 16.04 server, but I'm working in a corporate environment and am not able to `sudo -u postgres`  (I have sudo rights, but can't impersonate another user).

Is there any other way I can interact with my new Postgres service, or perhaps specify myself as an admin user during setup?

Comment: What happened when you tried to `sudo -u postgres`?

Comment: It asks for my sudo password, then says `Sorry, user my-user is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/psql' as postgres on my-server`

Comment: Well, you can sudo to root first, or put a bit of config in sudoers to let you sudo directly.

Answer (score 0):

You may grant yourself the necessary permissions assuming you have the right to edit PostgreSQL configuration under `/etc/postgresql`.

First, check what version of PostgreSQL is installed and the name of the cluster/instance (see the output of `pg_lsclusters`). For instance with Ubuntu 16.04 the version would be `9.5` with the default repository because that's what was current in 2016, and the instance would be named `main`.

In this case, the configuration is under `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main` (otherwise change the path according to version/cluster). In the configuration, you may  declare a mapping from your Unix user name to the postgres superuser database account, for instance:

In `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_ident.conf`

```
# MAPNAME       SYSTEM-USERNAME         PG-USERNAME
mymap           myusername              postgres
```

In `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf`, as the first rule (the order does matter):

```
# local      DATABASE  USER            METHOD  [OPTIONS]
local        all       postgres        peer map=mymap
```

Then reload (`sudo pg_ctlcluster 9.5 main reload`), and the Unix `myusername` account should be able to connect locally as superuser with:

```
$ psql -U postgres -d postgres
```

Otherwise check the server logs under `/var/log/postgresql`